# Use First() method on IQueryable without hitting a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm building IQueryable query expression with some filters. At a given moment, I want to check if expression has rows and depends on result to make another query. In the example below, `Any` causes hit on database so I have finally 3 hits on database.

Is there any way to reuse `Any` functionalities without hitting a database before time (something like `Where()` with all benefits).

```
IQueryable<Car> visibleCars = context.Cars.Where(c => c.Status == "V");
IQueryable<Car> invisibleCars = context.Cars.Where(c => c.Status == "I");
IQueryable<Car> c = visibleCars.Any() && invisibleCars.Any() 
                    ? context.Cars.Where(c => c.Status == "x").ToList();
```

Comment: How does that code even compile? In what way do you want `Any()` to work like `Where()`? You can pass a predicate to `Any()` if you like. Is that what you mean? Not that I think that would avoid an actual query on the DB. You need to cache the DB data, which may or may not be practical. It's not really clear what you expect to be able to accomplish here, nor have you provided enough details about the scenario to even really understand it.

Comment: `WHERE` is "just" building up your query - the parts of the ultimate `WHERE` clause. But with `Any()` or `First`, you want to know if there are any rows (for a given lambda expression) - and that **requires** access to the database - there's no way to check if rows exist or not *without* actually going to the database. Those two are **fundamentally** different operations - and **no**, you cannot check for existance or rows without a query against the database....

Comment: this code does certainly not compile. Something you might try is .Top(), which will return an IQueryable and therefore not execute immediately. However you'll always have your db hit when the compiler has to evaluate the expression.

Comment: You might try to get the union of those 3 sets (first "V", first "I" and all "x") and get that list on client side and then do additional check there. It will works fine if most of the time there are both visible and invisible cars as otherwise the query might returns a lot of useless rows... **Otherwise, maybe a stored procedure or an hand written query might be best.**

Comment: In default scenario Any() is an immediate method, so without wrapping it you cannot expect deferred execution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what is your goal? I do not see the reason to get rows with status x only if in the table there are rows with status V or I. With more details on what you are trying to do, I think we can lead you to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should be able to get a query that produces no results by making your other queries a part of your `where` clause.

```
IQueryable<Car> c = context.Cars
    .Where(c => c.Status == "x"
        && visibleCars.Any() 
        && invisibleCars.Any())
    .ToList();
```

As a more generalized approach, you can often use a trick with GroupBy to perform multiple checks in a single round-trip:

```
var interestingData = context.Cars
    .GroupBy(c => false)          // always get one result
    .Select(g => new
    {
        AnyVisibleCars = visibleCars.Any(),
        AnyInvisibleCars = invisibleCars.Any(),
        CarsWithXStatus = visibleCars.Any() && invisibleCars.Any()
            ? g.Where(c => c.Status == "x")
            : g.Where(c => false)
    })
    .Single();
```

Comment: Would this really work? Do you have an idea how the generated SQL would look like? I use NHibernate, which usually fails on such complex queries, so it would be cool if EF could handle this,

Comment: @Groo: The SQL for the first approach would be pretty gnarly, but it should work just fine. I don't know whether the database would be smart enough to optimize the query very well. Something like my second approach may perform better.

Comment: If you care about generated query, then use LinqPad (with the same driver as in your actual code)...